# Basic PHP/mySQL question ... Cycle through every row within a table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to cycle through each row for the particular field, grabbing its content, run it through a parser, and place the result back in the field. I rarely have to delve this far into things, so I working example would be greatly appreciated. Here's where I am at so far (please don't laugh!):

```
<?

    function parse_string($text){
        // do something with $text...
        return $text
    }

    $username="abcd";
    $password="1234";
    $database="abcdefg";
    $table="table2"
    $field="field3"

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    // And for the part I'd like help with...
    // Repeat through each row of $table, parsing the content of $field 
    // via the function parse_string($text) and placing the result back 
    // into the database (replacing $field)


    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: what's the parse_string() function do, there may be a way to this  with mysql

Comment: please stop using `@` to suppress errors , and stop using the outdated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: It's a DOM parser, designed to modify the encoding of whitespace from raw to named between HTML PRE tags.

Wouldn't be possible to do from a query, or so I imagine.

Comment: Sounds like this should have a "homework" tag on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function parse_string($text){
// do something with $text...
return $text
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [ TABLE NAME ]");
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $myresult[] = $row;
}

array_walk( $myresult, 'parse_string' );
```

I suggest use "CASE THEN" statement for your update query ( it's just 1 query instead of few like below )!

```
UPDATE [ TABLE NAME ] SET [FIELD] = CASE `id` WHEN 1 THEN XXXXX ...... END, 
                          [FIELD] = CASE `id` WHEN 1 THEN XXXXX ...... END, 
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          WHERE ..........
```

Comment: Thank you Hamid. Could you expand on the CASE THEN statement, and example would really help me out.

Comment: It's a question or statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable;");
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array() != null){
    echo $row["table_column"];
}
```

If you want to change the table values efficiently you have to do that inside the query

```
UPDATE mytables SET mycolumn = mycolumn + 1 WHERE mycolumn < 10;
```

Comment: Thank you  Ilia. Could you expand on how to update the table values from inside the query?